# How to send html external template in meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am using `Accounts.emailTemplates.enrollAccount.html`.
I can send e-mail successfully using this code:

```
   Accounts.emailTemplates.enrollAccount.html = function(user, url) {
      return '<h1>Thank you </h1><br/><a href="' + url + '">Verify eMail</a>';
  };
```

But what I want to do is, I have one external file called `email.html` and I want to send that file as an e-mail.
My code

```
  Accounts.emailTemplates.enrollAccount.html = function(user, url) {
      // i want to send email.html file from here or if you have other way
  };
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the meteor package `meteorhacks:ssr` like that :

```
Accounts.emailTemplates.enrollAccount.html = function(user, url) {
  SSR.compileTemplate('htmlEmailVerify', Assets.getText('email.html'));
  return SSR.render('htmlEmailVerify', {user: user, url: url});
};
```

And you can get the data inside the email html code with spacebars tags :
`{{user}}` & `{{url}}`